# Die Regenwolke zieht sich nach Norden (hin?)

Tags: grammar, prefix

Is it necessary to write the prefix 'hin' in the sentence? Will it change the meaning of the sentence if it's added ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to drop `sich` because that makes the sentence wrong gramatically. 
The sentence should be:

> Die Regenwolke zieht nach Norden (hin).

`hin` is unnecessary here and the sentence probably will sound weird to many people if it's included. It is not gramatically wrong to include it though.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to say?

The cloud is *moving* northwards?

The translation by adibender

> Die Regenwolke zieht nach Norden (hin).

is suitable then.

An old-fashioned translation for this meaning would also be:

> Die Regenwolke zieht *gen* Norden.

*gen* originates from *gegen* and means *towards* (the north).

But what about the translation from your question?

> Die Regenwolke zieht sich nach Norden (hin).

This one is also correct, but means something different: The cloud isn’t moving northwards, it is *stretched* in a northern direction. In this case, *hin* is also optional but if used it emphasizes this meaning (might differ locally).

*sich ziehen* is used to express the following:

- something takes a long time (*Die Bearbeitung des Antrags zieht sich hin.*)
- something extends over a longer distance (*Die Straße zieht sich durch das komplette Gebirge.*)

Comment: I heard it from the LOTR the rider of Rohan said : Reitet nach Norden!